# Sorting QObject children

Tags: qt, sorting, children, qobject

i noticed that QObject::children() method return a const reference to QObjectList, that contains the children of the qobject. Will it be safe to cast away the constness and sort the list with qSort?

Thanks
Anton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not do this. This is the definition of QObject::children():

```
inline const QObjectList &children() const { return d_ptr->children; }
```

This means you directly get the reference of the internal objectlist.
And the documentation says:

> Note that the list order changes when
>   QWidget children are raised or
>   lowered. A widget that is raised
>   becomes the last object in the list,
>   and a widget that is lowered becomes
>   the first object in the list.

It looks like a bad idea to mess with this list.

Comment: I checked the code for the QObject::lower() et al. It looks like they actually reorder this list manually, just as I would do it. te only difference is that QWidget is a friend of QObject, so QWidget has access to the d pimpl pointer, which gives it access to QObjectList without the constness. I will actually try this approach... If anything bad happens, I will post here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.  But why risk it?  Can't you just copy the `QObjectList` and sort your local copy?

Comment: Well, there are some reasons, I have couple `QObject` derived classes, that form a tree, and I want the leaves to be sorted in some way. Storing the copy is a way to go, but a few issues arise: 1) You have to keep the local copy up to date, when children are added/removed. 2) You can not call QObject::children() to get the children, a special function should be introduced on the derived classes (these classes do not share any base classes besides QObject), so there will be a good deal of repeating code.